# Password too short using AES/CFB/NoPadding, AES/OFB/NoPadding or AES/ CBC/NoPadding

Tags: java, encryption

Can someone help me reinforce or improve the following code to make the resulting passwords "longer".

I am humbly looking for the best way to use *AES/CFB/NoPadding*, or with *AES/CBC/NoPadding*, or with *AES/OFB/NoPadding*. We have tested with *AES/GCM/NOPADDING*. Which works with Java 8, but not with Java 7. And we need something that works in Java 7

For example, using '**safe**' as <key_to_encrypt>, and '**Bk206V4ytQ1zZAukPE6/2c5KUcxGYpBf**' as <encryption_key>, the pwd is: **FX5O5A==**
which is quite bite "small"

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.xml.security.utils.Base64;

public class StringEncrypt {

    private final static String ALG = "AES";
    private final static String CI = "AES/CFB/NoPadding";

    public static String encrypt(String cleartext, String key) throws Exception {   
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(key.getBytes());
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(md.digest());
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CI);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALG);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes());
        
        return new String(Base64.encode(encrypted));
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encrypted, String key) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(key.getBytes());
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(md.digest());

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CI);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALG);
        byte[] enc = Base64.decode(encrypted);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(enc);
        
        return new String(decrypted);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length == 2) {
            String pwd = StringEncrypt.encrypt(args[0], args[1]);
            System.out.println("Key encryption: " + pwd);
            pwd = StringEncrypt.decrypt(pwd, args[1]);
            if (args[0].equals(pwd)) {
                System.out.println("[OK] Correct decryption!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("[KO] Wrong decryption!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The parameters are required: <key_to_encrypt> <encryption_key>");
        }
    }

}
```

Stated differently, could someone give me an example of good encryption / decryption that works in Java 7?

Comment: CFB is a stream cipher mode, i.e. the size of the ciphertext is equal to the plaintext size (Base64 encoding increases the size by about 33%). The whole implementation seems to be a kind of password-based key derivation. There are dedicated algorithms for this, e.g. PBKDF2.

Comment: It's not that short: it's longer than 'safe' anyway

Comment: "safe" is a short and insecure password, no matter how you artificially grow it. What exactly is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: A "good" encryption/decryption code sample that works in Java 7

Comment: But what is the problem? There is no such thing as "good encryption". Just because you are using encryption, your software doesn't get any more secure. It all depends on the context. Please provide a complete description of what you are trying to solve.

Comment: If you are trying to hide the plaintext message size (i.e. your password size) then you should pad the plaintext *before performing the encryption*. E.g. you could add zero bytes up to 64 bytes, and then encrypt that. This question is asking for copy / paste encryption, but unfortunately copy / paste *security* doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to increase the length, you need to increase the byte count of the encrypted / decrypted parameter.
You could hack this by changing the charset although I don't think is best practice:

```
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16));

        return new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry ... I finally change to "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"

Comment: @JLLMNCHR GCM mode is not supported in Java7 (see the Cipher javadoc for supported options).  Using IV the same as key is like shooting yourself into the leg, you can completely break encryption with some modes. CBC requires a random IV (you can prepend the IV to pass it along the ciphertext)

Comment: Question to you Narcis: what kind of bytes can be in `decrypted`?